# Html Form With Array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, email

I have a big form and everything works, but when I add products with arrays I don't receive any numbers in an email just text saying "array"

It's my form, if I press the button it will repeat the same form with javascript you can check the image below:

[image: It's my form, if I press the button it will repeat the same form with javascript you can check the image below.]

On this image you can see the form repeat:

[image: On this image you can see the form repeat.]

```
<div class="gcore-line-tr gcore-form-row" id="ftr-multi-45">
  <div class="gcore-line-td" id="ftd-multi-45">
    <div class="gcore-subinput-container" id="fitem-Quant">
      <label for="Quant" class="gcore-label-left">Quantidade</label>
      <div class="gcore-input-container gcore-display-table gcore-input" id="fin-Quant">
        <input name="Quantidade[]" id="Quant" value="" placeholder="" class="" title="" style="" data-inputmask="" data-load-state="" data-tooltip="" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gcore-subinput-container" id="fitem-Caracteristicas"> 
      <label for="Caracteristicas" class="gcore-label-left">Designação</label>
      <div class="gcore-input-container gcore-display-table gcore-input" id="fin-Caracteristicas">
        <input name="Caracteristicas[]" id="Caracteristicas" value="" placeholder="" class="" title="" style="" data-inputmask="" data-load-state="" data-tooltip="" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gcore-subinput-container" id="fitem-Altura">
      <label for="Altura" class="gcore-label-left">Altura (cm)</label>
      <div class="gcore-input-container gcore-display-table gcore-input" id="fin-Altura">
        <input name="Altura[]" id="Altura" value="" placeholder="" class="" title="" style="" data-inputmask="" data-load-state="" data-tooltip="" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gcore-subinput-container" id="fitem-Largura">
      <label for="Largura" class="gcore-label-left">Largura (cm)</label>
      <div class="gcore-input-container gcore-display-table gcore-input" id="fin-Largura">
        <input name="Largura[]" id="Largura" value="" placeholder="" class="" title="" style="" data-inputmask="" data-load-state="" data-tooltip="" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="separator" style="background-size: cover;">
      <span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is why I receive an array in an email if I want to add multiple products.

I use to create $ (I use PHPMailer)
I send here the $ items code:
[image: I send here the $ items code]

```
 // ESTORE 1
 $Quantidade = $_POST['Quantidade'];
 $Caracteristicas = $_POST['Caracteristicas'];
 $Altura = $_POST['Altura'];
 $Largura = $_POST['Largura'];
```

I use to send values

```
$mail->Body ="
    
    <p><h3> | ORÇAMENTO - ONLINE PEDIDO</h3></p>
    <p><h3>⇰ Informação Cliente:</h3></p>
    <h3>▪ Tipo de cliente ( 0 = Particular | 1 = Empresa):</h3> $empresa  <br>
    <h3>▪ Nome Empresa:</h3> $empresa_nome <br>
    <h3>▪ Montagem ( 0 = Nao Quero Montagem | 1 = Quero Montagem):</h3> $montagem  <br>
    <h3>▪ Local de montagem:</h3> $morada_montagem <br>
    <h3>▪ Primeiro Nome:</h3> $name <br>
    <h3>▪ Ultimo Nome: </h3>$nomeultimo <br>
    <h3>▪ Email:</h3> $email <br> 
    <h3>▪ Nº Telefone:</h3> $phone <br> 
    <h3>▪ NIF:</h3> $nif <br> 
    <h3>▪ Morada: </h3>$morada <br>
    <h3>▪ Cidade: </h3>$localidade <br>
    <h3>▪ Código Postal:</h3> $codigopostal  <br>
 
    <p><h3>⇰ Informação Produto:</h3></p>
     ---------------------------------------------<br>

    <p><h3>⇰ Produtos:</h3></p>
     <h3>▪ Tipo de Estore:</h3> $Caracteristicas
    <h3>▪ Largura:</h3> $Largura 
    <h3>▪ Altura: </h3>$Altura
    <h3>▪ Quantidade:</h3> $Quantidade <br> 
    ---------------------------------------------<br>
    
     <h3>▪ Acionamento:</h3> $adicionamento <br>
    
    <h3>▪ Visita do Tecnico:</h3> $tecnico  <br>
   
    <h3>▪ Mensagem :</h3> $message<br>
    <p><h3>Cliente aceita (política de privacidade)</h3>$politicaprivacidade<br></p>
    
     <p><img src=\"cid:logoimg\" /></p>";

    foreach ($Caracteristicas as $item) { echo $item."<br/>"; }
    foreach ($Quantidade as $item) { echo $item."<br/>"; }
    foreach ($Altura as $item) { echo $item."<br/>"; }
    foreach ($Largura as $item) { echo $item."<br/>"; }
```

Result in an email:

[image: email result]

Thank you.

When I added

```
    foreach ($Caracteristicas as $item) { echo $item."<br/>"; }
    foreach ($Quantidade as $item) { echo $item."<br/>"; }
    foreach ($Altura as $item) { echo $item."<br/>"; }
    foreach ($Largura as $item) { echo $item."<br/>"; }
```

I have this as result in the browser:
[image: Its shows the number I insert in form , but cant see them in email]

Comment: Well, what did you expect to happen, exactly? An array is a list of data, it has no built-in visual representation (largely because it has no guaranteed structure within it). You need to decide how you want to display that data and write some code to loop through the array and output the data in the format you want. At the absolute simplest, you could write something like: `foreach ($Caracteristicas as $item) { echo $item."<br/>"; }` (this should work since it looks like in this case the items in the arrays are not also objects/arrays themselves.)

Comment: wow, thank you! I want to receive the results of arrays by email.
I tried your option and it writes in the browser list of the array as result. But how I receive that result via email?

Comment: Exactly the same...you use PHP to generate the email contents, I assume? otherwise I don't know how you generated the content you showed in your picture?

Comment: Thank you for dedicate you time to help me. I will explain what happen.
I created:
[code]
    foreach ($Caracteristicas as $item) { echo $item."<br/>"; }
    foreach ($Quantidade as $item) { echo $item."<br/>"; }
    foreach ($Altura as $item) { echo $item."<br/>"; }
    foreach ($Largura as $item) { echo $item."<br/>"; }
[/code]
and I use to send information:

[code]
     <h3>▪ Tipo de Estore:</h3> $Caracteristicas
    <h3>▪ Largura:</h3> $Largura 
    <h3>▪ Altura: </h3>$Altura
    <h3>▪ Quantidade:</h3> $Quantidade <br> 
[/code]
I just received "array" as result via email.

Comment: To be clear, I meant you can just concatenate the values into your email string instead of echoing them.

Comment: Thank you :) I tried everything.. but is exactly the same. Sorry, I'm new to this. I can see the array result in the browser but I don't receive It via email.

Comment: Show exactly how you are generating the email string and sending the email, please. You showed some HTML with some PHP variables inside them, but it was out of context.

Comment: P.S. Please use the "edit" button under your question to add more code, do not paste it into these comments - thanks :)

Comment: I think now everything is more easy to understand!

Comment: Thanks. See answer below. Please mark it as "accepted" if it helps you.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow!  Just a wee reminder that it's best to include any code as text rather than an image - as discussed in this meta post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is a list of data, it has no built-in visual representation (largely because it has no guaranteed structure within it). You need to decide how you want to display that data and write some code to loop through the array and output the data in the format you want.

At the absolute simplest you can just output each item on a separate line, or separated by commas. For that you need to build up the mail body string gradually so you can concatenate the values together. To make for less repetition, a function would be useful here, so you can use it to display the contents of all the arrays in a consistent way.

Something like this should work:

```
function arrayToString($arr)
{
  $output = "";
  foreach ($arr as $item) $output .= $item."<br>";
  return $output;
}

$mail->Body ="

<p><h3> | ORÇAMENTO - ONLINE PEDIDO</h3></p>


<p><h3>⇰ Informação Cliente:</h3></p>


<h3>▪ Tipo de cliente ( 0 = Particular | 1 = Empresa):</h3> $empresa  <br>
<h3>▪ Nome Empresa:</h3> $empresa_nome <br>
<h3>▪ Montagem ( 0 = Nao Quero Montagem | 1 = Quero Montagem):</h3> $montagem  <br>
<h3>▪ Local de montagem:</h3> $morada_montagem <br>
<h3>▪ Primeiro Nome:</h3> $name <br>
<h3>▪ Ultimo Nome: </h3>$nomeultimo <br>
<h3>▪ Email:</h3> $email <br> 
<h3>▪ Nº Telefone:</h3> $phone <br> 
<h3>▪ NIF:</h3> $nif <br> 
<h3>▪ Morada: </h3>$morada <br>
<h3>▪ Cidade: </h3>$localidade <br>
<h3>▪ Código Postal:</h3> $codigopostal  <br>

<p><h3>⇰ Informação Produto:</h3></p>
 ---------------------------------------------<br>
 
 
 

<p><h3>⇰ Produtos:</h3></p>
 <h3>▪ Tipo de Estore:</h3>".arrayToString($Caracteristicas)."
<h3>▪ Largura:</h3> ".arrayToString($Largura)." 
<h3>▪ Altura: </h3>".arrayToString($Altura)."
<h3>▪ Quantidade:</h3>".arrayToString($Quantidade)."<br> 
---------------------------------------------<br>


 <h3>▪ Acionamento:</h3> $adicionamento <br>

<h3>▪ Visita do Tecnico:</h3> $tecnico  <br>

<h3>▪ Mensagem :</h3> $message<br>
<p><h3>Cliente aceita (política de privacidade)</h3>$politicaprivacidade<br></p>

 <p><img src=\"cid:logoimg\" /></p>";
```

Comment: I don't know how but it works perfectly. Are you a magician? 
Really thank you. I'm so happy I was here for 4 days. And you came and save my day!
Really :) Thank you from bottom of my heart!

Comment: `I don't know how`...then you need to try and understand, because string concatenation and array looping are quite basic functionality, you are likely to use them all the time if you continue to do any programming. What part(s) of the code I wrote are puzzling to you? I can try to explain if you like.

Comment: I have read all the code for 3 times.. hmm I think i got it :) And the way its works, Sorry I just work with PHP for 4 days just trying to learn by my self.

Btw, you have any suggetion how is possible separate each value in email. I mean I want to show the products  in better way.

What I see how its like

Tipo de Estore: 1,2,3,4  Largura: 1,2,3,4 etc.. you know? And i want to make this looks more organized.

Comment: Well that depends on how exactly you would prefer it to look instead?

Comment: If real I want to show like: Imagine my form add products the name, how many and sizes.
I want to receive an email like: Product, size, and how many. Because at the moment if I add more than 1 products I will receive an email like: Product Product, size, size, how many, how many.

Comment: Ok. That sounds like it should be the subject of a new question. Post a new question, and comment here to give me a link to it, then I will take a look.

Comment: Now I have no permissions to create new one. Soon as possible i WIll create and send you link here :) have a lovely day!

Comment: A friend of mine helped me :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67740426/php-email-array-organization to create a post.

Comment: Oh! Dont worry :) thank you for help not your foult! I can vote up you question anyway.
I tryed you code give me some errors but I will create a new post in the future ! Thank you

Comment: I got this one! https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDGY6.png

Comment: Put your comments about that on the post where I actually provided the answer, thanks.