# PHP EMAIL ARRAY ORGANIZATION

Tags: php, html, arrays, email

So I have a little question hope you can solve my simple problem.

I have an HTML form with ARRAY. Where I insert multiple product.

[Part of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlYSi.png)

Everything works great. I recive an email with values.
But in my case when I recive infomation in email its looks like this:

[My form information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8hkQ.png)
[What I recive in email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OuUW.png)

My objetive is (If possible to create like groups)

To recive an email like:

Product 1:
1
2
3
4
5

Product 2:

1
2
3
4
5

-------------------PHP BODY

```
 <?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require_once 'phpmailer/Exception.php';
require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
require_once 'phpmailer/SMTP.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$my_path ='phpmailer/uploads';
$alert = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$nomeultimo = $_POST['nomeultimo'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$morada = $_POST['morada'];
$localidade = $_POST['localidade'];
$codigopostal = $_POST['codigopostal'];
$montagem = $_POST['montagem'];
$adicionamento = $_POST['adicionamento'];
$empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
$empresa_nome = $_POST['empresa_nome'];
    
//MONTAGEM
$montagem = $_POST['montagem'];
$morada_montagem = $_POST['morada_montagem'];
    
$nif = $_POST['nif'];
// ESTORE 1
$Quantidade = $_POST['Quantidade'];
$Colecao = $_POST['Colecao'];
$Caracteristicas = $_POST['Caracteristicas'];
$Altura = $_POST['Altura'];
$Largura = $_POST['Largura'];

//$pretendidos_estores = $_POST['pretendidos_estores'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$tecnico = $_POST['tecnico'];
$politicaprivacidade = $_POST['politicaprivacidade'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

  try{
{

  $output = "";
  foreach ($arr as $item) $output .= $item."<br/>";
  return $output;
}

$mailContent = " <p><h3>ORÇAMENTO - ONLINE PEDIDO</h3></p>
<p><h3>⇰ Informação Cliente:</h3></p>
<h3>▪ Tipo de cliente ( 0 = Particular | 1 = Empresa):</h3> $empresa  <br>
<h3>▪ Nome Empresa:</h3> $empresa_nome <br>
<h3>▪ Montagem ( 0 = Nao Quero Montagem | 1 = Quero Montagem):</h3> $montagem  <br>
<h3>▪ Local de montagem:</h3> $morada_montagem <br>
<h3>▪ Primeiro Nome:</h3> $name <br>
<h3>▪ Ultimo Nome: </h3>$nomeultimo <br>
<h3>▪ Email:</h3> $email <br> 
<h3>▪ Nº Telefone:</h3> $phone <br> 
<h3>▪ NIF:</h3> $nif <br> 
<h3>▪ Morada: </h3>$morada <br>
<h3>▪ Cidade: </h3>$localidade <br>
<h3>▪ Código Postal:</h3> $codigopostal  <br>
        
  <p><h3>⇰ Informação Produto:</h3></p>
     ---------------------------------------------<br>
     
 <p><h3>⇰ Produtos:</h3></p>";
        
for ($i = 0; $i < count($Caracteristicas); $i++)
{
  $mailContent .= $Caracteristicas[$i].", ".$Colecao[$i].", ".$Largura[$i].", ".$Altura[$i].", ".$Quantidade[$i];
}
$mailContent .= "
---------------------------------------------<br>

$mail->Body = $mailContent;

<h3>▪ Visita do Tecnico:</h3> $tecnico  <br>
<h3>▪ Mensagem :</h3> $message<br>
<p><h3>Cliente aceita (política de privacidade)</h3>$politicaprivacidade<br></p>
<p><img src=\"cid:logoimg\" /></p>";
      
foreach ($_FILES["attachment"]["name"] as $k => $v) {
    $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"][$k], $_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$k] );
}     
      
    $mail->send();
    $alert = '<div class="alert-success">
                 <span>O seu orçamento foi pedido com sucesso. Em breve iremos enviar um email.<br>
                 Obrigado!</span>
                </div>';
  } catch  (Exception $e){
    $alert = '<div class="alert-error">
                <span>'.$e->getMessage().'</span>
              </div>';
  }
}
?>
```

--------------- HTML CODE

```
          <div class="black-border">

                                                    <div class="gcore-line-tr gcore-form-row" id="ftr-multi-23">

                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="gcore-line-tr gcore-form-row" id="ftr-multi-45">

                                                        <div class="gcore-line-td" id="ftd-multi-45">
                                                            <h4 class="id-color">ADICIONAR ESTORE</h4><br>
       
                                                            <div class="gcore-subinput-container" id="fitem-Quant">
                                                                <div class="gcore-input-container gcore-display-table gcore-input" id="fin-Quant"><input class="form-control" name="Quantidade[]" id="Quant" value="" placeholder="Quantidade" class="" title="" style="" data-inputmask="" data-load-state="" data-tooltip="" type="text"></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="gcore-subinput-container" id="fitem-Caracteristicas">
                                                                <div class="gcore-input-container gcore-display-table gcore-input" id="fin-Caracteristicas"><input class="form-control" name="Caracteristicas[]" id="Caracteristicas" value="" placeholder="Modelo Estore" class="" title="" style="" data-inputmask="" data-load-state="" data-tooltip="" type="text"></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="gcore-subinput-container" id="fitem-Colecao">
                                                                <div class="gcore-input-container gcore-display-table gcore-input" id="fin-Colecao"><input class="form-control" name="Colecao[]" id="Colecao" value="" placeholder="Coleção" class="" title="" style="" data-inputmask="" data-load-state="" data-tooltip="" type="text"></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="gcore-subinput-container " id="fitem-Altura">
                                                                <div class="gcore-input-container gcore-display-table gcore-input" id="fin-Altura"><input class="form-control" name="Altura[]" id="Altura" value="" placeholder="Altura (cm)" class="" title="" style="" data-inputmask="" data-load-state="" data-tooltip="" type="text"></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="gcore-subinput-container" id="fitem-Largura">
                                                                <div class="gcore-input-container gcore-display-table gcore-input" id="fin-Largura"><input class="form-control" name="Largura[]" id="Largura" value="" placeholder="Largura (cm)" class="" title="" style="" data-inputmask="" data-load-state="" data-tooltip="" type="text"></div>
                                                            </div>


                                                            <div class="separator" style="background-size: cover;"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></span></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="gcore-line-tr gcore-form-row" id="ftr-custom4">
                                                        <div class="gcore-line-td" id="ftd-custom4">
                                                            <div class="gcore-display-table gcore-input" id="fin-custom4">
                                                                <div class="btn btn-line" id="add_row">Novo Estore</div>
                                                                <script>
                                                                    jQuery('#add_row').click(function() {
                                                                        var clone = jQuery('#ftr-multi-45 .gcore-line-td').first().clone();
                                                                        clone.find('input').val('')
                                                                        jQuery('#ftr-multi-45.gcore-line-tr').append(clone);
                                                                    })

                                                                </script>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
```

[Image of PHP CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VI8f.png)

ERROR IMAGE: [ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDGY6.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code. It makes it hard to read, and impossible for people to quote or edit, or run any parts of it themselves. Please also have a look at the tips on [ask] and producing a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to pick one of the arrays and loop through that with a `for` loop so you get a counter. You can then pick the item from each of the arrays matching the current counter and display it - this gets you the results which belong together.

(For it to work, all the arrays must have the same number of items in them, but from what you've shown that shouldn't be a problem.

Try something like this:

```
$mailContent = "<p><h3>ESTORES RAINHA | ORÇAMENTO - ONLINE PEDIDO</h3></p>


<p><h3>⇰ Informação Cliente:</h3></p>


<h3>▪ Tipo de cliente ( 0 = Particular | 1 = Empresa):</h3> $empresa  <br>
<h3>▪ Nome Empresa:</h3> $empresa_nome <br>
<h3>▪ Montagem ( 0 = Nao Quero Montagem | 1 = Quero Montagem):</h3> $montagem  <br>
<h3>▪ Local de montagem:</h3> $morada_montagem <br>
<h3>▪ Primeiro Nome:</h3> $name <br>
<h3>▪ Ultimo Nome: </h3>$nomeultimo <br>
<h3>▪ Email:</h3> $email <br> 
<h3>▪ Nº Telefone:</h3> $phone <br> 
<h3>▪ NIF:</h3> $nif <br> 
<h3>▪ Morada: </h3>$morada <br>
<h3>▪ Cidade: </h3>$localidade <br>
<h3>▪ Código Postal:</h3> $codigopostal  <br>

<p><h3>⇰ Informação Produto:</h3></p>
 ---------------------------------------------<br>

<p><h3>⇰ Produtos:</h3></p>";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($Caracteristicas); $i++)
{
  $mailContent .= $Caracteristicas[$i].", ".$Colecao[$i].", ".$Largura[$i].", ".$Altura[$i].", ".$Quantitdade[$i];
}
$mailContent .= "<br> 
---------------------------------------------<br>";

$mail->Body = $mailContent;
```

Obviously you can make the formatting of the string more sophisticated, as per your requirements. This is just to give you the basic idea of how to loop over the arrays.

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for answer! :)

You help me a lot! 

Im trying your code but its give me an error :(

Maybe i do something wrong!

I can edit code and show you (PHP one)

Thank you!

Comment: I have added error image in post !

Comment: That's because the original code you showed failed to include the entire HTML of the email. So I ended the string after `--------<br>` but it looks like you have HTML content after that. However now it looks to PHP like it should be PHP code, not string content. Just get rid of the `";` at the end of the `--------<br>";` bit in the code I provided. P.S. That's a trivial syntax error which ought to be obvious from the highlighting and the error message and the obvious HTML outside a string...did you really need to ask??

Comment: I have tryed but give me and error in line for ($i = 0; $i < count($Caracteristicas); $i++)
I really need to use  $mailContent = " in start?
Sorry for that questions.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/K406Z5n.png

Comment: Well obviously you need to remove the $mail->Body bit from the start of that picture. What do you think it is doing, all by itself, incomplete? Obviously the $mailContent bit replaced it. I used a variable so we could build up the email string gradually (allowing the loops to work) and then pass it to the mail body at the end, when it's ready. You may be a beginner but you do need to put a little bit of thought into what the code might actually be doing and try to reason. And if you don't realise that `$mail->Body = "` is an incomplete line, then you need to go back to your PHP lesson 1.

Comment: yeah you right :/ i will check lessons! today all night! I understand what code do but when I write by my self from 0, sometimes isnt easy but yeah !

Thank you for help. Hope it will be a last question today! 

https://i.snipboard.io/Elvxts.jpg I have an problem here I tryed to code but give more errors :/ I have an error in line where for starts! My error is: https://i.snipboard.io/rDQ2uG.jpg

Comment: In your new version. `$mail->Body = $mailContent;` is in the wrong place. It should be _below_ the line which ends with `</p>";`, but above the `foreach`. Again you've left that same chunk of HTML all by itself, outside a string, which makes the PHP invalid. (In the picture in your code, the `$mail->Body = $mailContent;` line was in the correct place. I have no idea why you moved it.

Comment: I have tryed! And you right have no logic the HTML being alone by his self under the  $mail-> Body.

But I think I have some touble with  for ($i = 0; $i < count($Caracteristicas); $i++)

Because I always got an error in that part https://i.snipboard.io/HNuMjv.jpg
 thanks for suggetions!

Comment: Paste your current code as text into the question please, then I can test it myself. I can't do that from a picture, because I can't copy and paste it. Thanks.

Comment: Hey! Thank you. I send you my php code here: https://www.codepile.net/pile/V9167V2m
and HTML only part you need: https://www.codepile.net/pile/L0oOxx0o

Comment: No, **into the question** please, not on another site.

Comment: Im sorry I cant paste , the text looks not configurated. :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting explains how to make it look correct.

Comment: Thank you works perfectly. Already edited i had a little mistakes but glad to you help me so much. Hope is enoghut to you understand,

Comment: Good morning, I have tryed for same days. But still have an error. You dont need to waste your time but I will be really glad. I started 2 days ago learn php from 0 and discovered many new things thank you.

Comment: Sorry I was busy all weekend. Looks like I made a typo, which you copied: `$Altura[$]` should be `$Altura[$i]`. Small details can be very important in programming!

Comment: Hey no problem! Enjoy your time, thanks for you dedication ! real, is i found it and tryed but keep the same error in line : 129 on this cas is for ($i = 0; $i < count($Caracteristicas); $i++)

Comment: What exactly does the error message say now?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR) in C:\xampp\htdocs\pedido_orcamento.php on line 129

Comment: There's another small typo: `</p>;"` (on the line just before the `for`) should be `</p>";`. It's correct in my version...I'm not sure how it ended up being wrong in yours - surely you used copy and paste??

Comment: After that, the line `$mail->Body = $mailContent` needs a `;` on the end. Again, it's correct in my version. Further down you also have a `catch` without a `try`. You need to a) copy more accurately, b) learn the very basics of PHP syntax (like always put a `;` at the end of each line!), and c) double-check your work more carefully. Also maybe d) use an IDE or code editor which has better syntax checking and could highlight this to you - for example Visual Studio Code, when used with the PHP plugins, can do this very well.

Comment: You also right! Works perfecly! I tryed some changes, I found and error but now I have fixed it by my self you right we need to learn by our self if we do that we can learn more. I already had a try but didn't show because private information but thank you!

I have a little error here (Message body empty) I have tryed to fix changing $mail->Body = $mailContent; to $mail->Body  $mailContent; but still same. I also updated the code  on top.

Thank you

Comment: `$mail->Body $mailContent;` would be a syntax error. `=` is how you assign values in PHP. Again - study the basics. Anyway I can't see any reason from your code why the email body would be empty, that doesn't make too much sense. The only thing I can think is that you didn't tell PHPMailer it's a HTML email. Try using `$mail->isHTML(true); ` and also [consult the documentation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: Thank you! The fix is, $mail->Body = $mailContent;  need to be in the end! after <p><img src=\"cid:logoimg\" /></p>"; I have tryed and working now.

Comment: Yes, I already explained that in an earlier comment - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67740426/php-email-array-organization/67740792?noredirect=1#comment119744459_67740792